# How do I see what questions have new comments?

Tags: support, comments

"Active" seems only to track answers and edits, but not comments (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: [A related meta.SO question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63830)

Answer (score 1):

Comments on your posts, or directed as comment replies to your `@name` will appear in the global inbox (click the Stack Exchange logo in the upper left).

There is no sort order that reflects comments.

We view comments as "post-it notes" on the real units of work in the Q&A system, questions and answers, so they are intentionally deprioritized.